# How to return the list of the highest occurring anagrams within an array?

Tags: java, arrays, anagram

I have a question about how to return the list of sorted anagrams that are placed adjacently in the indexes of a single array. To clarify this:

Array sortedAnagrams: 
sortedAnagrams[0] = asp 
sortedAnagrams[1] = pas 
sortedAnagrams[2] = code 
sortedAnagrams[3] = coed 
sortedAnagrams[4] = deco 
sortedAnagrams[5] = France

From this example, it is clear that my indices "2","3", & "4" have the highest occurring anagram. How do I write a method where I can say these indices contain the highest occurring anagram?

I started of doing this but I don't know how it should continue.

```
public static String[] getLargestAnagramGroup(String[] stringList){

    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.length; i++) {
        int j = i + 1;
        if (AnagramUtil.areAnagrams(stringList[i],stringList[j]) == true) {
            j++;
        } else {
            i = j;
        } 
    }
    return null; // for now 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] ListOfSortedAnagrams = new String[] {"asp", "pas", "code", "coed", "deco" , "France" }
    System.out.print("Most occurring anagrams are: " + AnagramUtil.getLargestAnagramGroup(String[] ListOfSortedAnagrams));
```

Results:
    Most occurring anagrams are: code, coed, deco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could normalize strings for example sort chars in string and group them by this normalized value.

Have a look at :

```
public class Anagram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listAnagrams = new String[]{"asp", "pas", "code", "coed", "deco", "France"};
        Map<String, List<String>> countMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String str : listAnagrams) {
            String normalized = normalize(str);
            List<String> strings = countMap.getOrDefault(normalized, new ArrayList<>());
            strings.add(str);
            countMap.put(normalized, strings);
        }
        Optional<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> max = countMap.entrySet().stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().size()));

        System.out.print("Most occurring anagrams are: " + max.get().getValue());
    }

    private static String normalize(String inputString){
        char[] tempArray = inputString.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);
        return new String(tempArray);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Most occurring anagrams are: [code, coed, deco]
```

PS: It could be refactored with stream group but I think it will be less readable.

**Update**:
Here is stream group version:

```
public class Anagram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listAnagrams = new String[]{"asp", "pas", "code", "coed", "deco", "France"};

        Optional<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> maxNormalised = Arrays.stream(listAnagrams)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Anagram::normalize))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().size()));

        System.out.print("Most occurring anagrams are: " + maxNormalised.get().getValue());
    }

    private static String normalize(String inputString){
        char[] tempArray = inputString.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);
        return new String(tempArray);
    }
}
```